# Magento2 error while extension installation in create backup step

Tags: php, extensions, magento2.2.2, composer

In my `magento2` store I want to install the extension. I have tried this **via composer as well as admin extension  manager**. Every time the process failed in Backup stage after generating the 4Gb of data process automatically stop with below error,

> Warning: stat(): stat failed for
>   /vendor/magento/module-page-cache/view/frontend/web/js/page-cache-bak.js
>   in /vendor/magento/framework/Archive/Tar.php on line 324

[image]

I have google regarding this error, but didn’t find any solution. Can anyone tell me why this issue occurs and how to solve this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you getting this error, while setup:upgrade?

Comment: No create backup step check the screen of admin where I get this error 
https://i.imgur.com/RMaojGR.png

Comment: Also if I run the `php bin/magento setup:backup --code --db --media` this command from composer then also this error occure

Comment: This error occurs when your server doesn't have enough space to store the backup data.  Try to check it

Comment: I have already checked that but server has enough space almost 50GB space available.